# SharePoint backward compatability with Chrome

Tags: sharepoint-server, chrome

The UI of the ribbons and certain styles on the SharePoint forms seems to not appear very well on chrome, while JQuery workaround can always be applied, is there any fixes that can be applied to the masterpage that helps with this issue? we have SharePoint 2010 in the organisation. any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

**Update:** 
Here is a picture of the Items Tag in Chrome, while I have custom Jquery on different lists, I don't have one on this particular list and this behavior is consistent across different sites in Chrome.

[image]

Comment: SharePoint 2010 should work just fine with Chrome! Do you have any JavaScript customizations that might influence? Also, have you applied the latest Service Pack to the SharePoint farm?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, please see the update above and a picture of the issue, as of the service pack, we have the one from April 2016.

Comment: I found out from our admin that our configuration in Prod is Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1), Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2775353) 64-Bit Edition 
Cumulative update package (SharePoint server-package): April 9, 2013